# Finding sorted subarrays in array

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I am working on sorting algorithms and I am trying to improve mergeSort by locating already sorted subArrays.

```
public static void mergeSort(int[] array)
{
    if(array == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    if(array.length > 1)
    {
        int mid = array.length / 2;

        // left
        int[] left = new int[mid];
        for(int i = 0; i < mid; i++)
        {
            left[i] = array[i];
        }
         
        //right
        int[] right = new int[array.length - mid];
        for(int i = mid; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            right[i - mid] = array[i];
        }
        //recursively calls
        mergeSort(left);
        mergeSort(right);

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int k = 0;

        //  left and right merged
        while(i < left.length && j < right.length)
        {
            if(left[i] < right[j])
            {
                array[k] = left[i];
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                array[k] = right[j];
                j++;
            }
            k++;
        }
        // left overs
        while(i < left.length)
        {
            array[k] = left[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        while(j < right.length)
        {
            array[k] = right[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know anything about the data you're sorted, with regards to runs of increasing or decreasing elements?

Comment: Please explain what is the problem with the code you posted. Can you provide input for which the output is not correct (or for which you get an error, or for which the code hangs)?

Comment: @Dave the data is a random unsorted array of ints.

Comment: @trincot There is currently nothing wrong with the code, I am trying to improve it by locating subarrays and repeatedly merging the adjacent pairs of sorted regions until the array is completely sorted

Comment: Look for `natural merge sort`

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called natural merge sort. Before you start with sorting the dataset you will do one run to identify all the presorted data. The mergesort itself stays the same.

I found some example code for you at: [happycoders](https://github.com/SvenWoltmann/sorting-algorithms-ultimate-guide/blob/main/src/main/java/eu/happycoders/sort/method/mergesort/NaturalMergeSort.java)

```
package eu.happycoders.sort.method.mergesort;

import eu.happycoders.sort.method.Counters;
import eu.happycoders.sort.method.SortAlgorithm;

/**
 * Natural merge sort implementation for performance tests.
 *
 * @author <a href="sven@happycoders.eu">Sven Woltmann</a>
 */
public class NaturalMergeSort implements SortAlgorithm {

  @Override
  public void sort(int[] elements) {
    int numElements = elements.length;

    int[] tmp = new int[numElements];
    int[] starts = new int[numElements + 1];

    // Step 1: identify runs
    int runCount = 0;
    starts[0] = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= numElements; i++) {
      if (i == numElements || elements[i] < elements[i - 1]) {
        starts[++runCount] = i;
      }
    }

    // Step 2: merge runs, until only 1 run is left
    int[] from = elements;
    int[] to = tmp;

    while (runCount > 1) {
      int newRunCount = 0;

      // Merge two runs each
      for (int i = 0; i < runCount - 1; i += 2) {
        merge(from, to, starts[i], starts[i + 1], starts[i + 2]);
        starts[newRunCount++] = starts[i];
      }

      // Odd number of runs? Copy the last one
      if (runCount % 2 == 1) {
        int lastStart = starts[runCount - 1];
        System.arraycopy(from, lastStart, to, lastStart,
              numElements - lastStart);
        starts[newRunCount++] = lastStart;
      }

      // Prepare for next round...
      starts[newRunCount] = numElements;
      runCount = newRunCount;

      // Swap "from" and "to" arrays
      int[] help = from;
      from = to;
      to = help;
    }

    // If final run is not in "elements", copy it there
    if (from != elements) {
      System.arraycopy(from, 0, elements, 0, numElements);
    }
  }

  private void merge(int[] source, int[] target, int startLeft,
                     int startRight, int endRight) {
    int leftPos = startLeft;
    int rightPos = startRight;
    int targetPos = startLeft;

    // As long as both arrays contain elements...
    while (leftPos < startRight && rightPos < endRight) {
      // Which one is smaller?
      int leftValue = source[leftPos];
      int rightValue = source[rightPos];
      if (leftValue <= rightValue) {
        target[targetPos++] = leftValue;
        leftPos++;
      } else {
        target[targetPos++] = rightValue;
        rightPos++;
      }
    }
    // Copy the rest
    while (leftPos < startRight) {
      target[targetPos++] = source[leftPos++];
    }
    while (rightPos < endRight) {
      target[targetPos++] = source[rightPos++];
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void sort(int[] elements, Counters counters) {
    // Not implemented
  }

}
```